# Discrepancy on a limit of a 2-variable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the limit below. However when I evaluate the function approximating to it from both axes, one at a time i get different values.

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (1,\pi)}f(x,y)=\frac{\cos(xy)}{1-x-\cos(y)}$$

Approximating from y-axis:

$$\lim \limits_{(0,y)\to (1,\pi)}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-\cos(y)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

However, from x-axis:

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (1,\pi)}f(x,0)=\frac{1}{-x}=-1$$

Thus, if approximating this point from different directions i get different values, the limit shouldn't exist. Nonetheless it exists and is equal to -1. What am I understanding or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your approximation using the axes you should set $y=\pi$ and $x=1$ in each case. Setting each one to zero you're approximating other points. We indeed have
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 1} f(x,\pi) = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2-x} = -1 = f(1,\pi)
$$
$$
\lim\limits_{y\to \pi} f(1,y) = \lim\limits_{y\to \pi} \frac{\cos(y)}{-\cos(y)} = -1
$$
Hence, the continuity of $f$ implies that 
$$
\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,\pi)} f(x,y) = -1
$$
To see that $f$ is continuous just note that it is given by the quotient of continuous functions and the denominator doesn't vanish at the point $(1,\pi)$.